# How to send entire http request from file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, python-requests, request

I am writing a small application that interprets the http response of a request. I am writing the application in python. I have not found anything that allows me to send the body + headers stored in one file. I can send certain parts like the headers but not the entire request.
For example, if the request is:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Cookie: bob=lemon
```

I want to send this entire request in one go. How would I do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the python requests library. https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request

For the request above it would look something like

```
import requests 

url = 'http://localhost:[YOUR PORT HERE]/'
cookies = {bob : lemon}

r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
```

To check if you had a successful request you should get a 200 code from.

```
r.status_code
```

Check out the library for more, it is very extensive.

Comment: Thanks, but I already stated this above. I do not want to hard code the url. I can change the headers but not the entire request. I am looking for a way to send the entire request through the file.